# MongoDB Aggregation Framework sample rate

Tags: mongodb, sample-rate

I want to try MongoDB for my database solution, so I'm playing around with it. The [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) is perfect and most of the documentation explains me very well what I have to do.

My data look like this:

```
{ "_id" :       ObjectId("54e5e79032d4796d1dec195e"), 
  "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-01-20T10:31:02.082Z"), 
  "value" :     4089 }
```

For example, if I want to aggregate my data per second, this is what I would do:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate(
 {
   $match : {
      timestamp: {$gte: ISODate("2015-01-21T12:00:00Z"), 
                  $lte: ISODate("2015-01-21T12:01:00Z")}   
   }
 },
 {
   $group : {
    _id : { $second: "$timestamp" },
    averageQuantity: { $avg: "$value" },
    count: { $sum: 1 }
  }
 }
);
```

My question is, what do I have to do to aggregate my data by a sample rate that's *not* [predefined](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/), like $second or $minute, but let's say by 30 seconds?

Using the code from my example, I would like to get 2 results returned.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what do I have to do to aggregate my data by a sample rate that's not predefined, like $second or $minute, but let's say by 30 seconds?

A lot of math in the aggregation pipeline. If you want to take a day's worth of time and group by 30 second intervals, for example, you'll need to take the `timestamp` and compute how many seconds into the day it represents, then turn that into a rounded # of 30 second intervals into the day and group on that.

```
db.mycollection.aggregate([
    { "$project" : {
        "secs" : { 
            "$add" : [
                { "$multiply" : [{ "$hour" : "$timestamp"}, 60, 60] },
                { "$multiply" : [{ "$minute" : "$timestamp"}, 60] }
                { "$second" : "$timestamp"}
            ]
        }
        "value" : 1
    } },
    { "$group" : {
        "_id" : {
            "$divide" : [
                { "$subtract" : [
                    "$secs", 
                    { "$mod" : ["$secs", 30] }
                ] },
                30
            ]
        },
        "value" : { "$sum" : "$value" }
    } }
])
```

Comment: Thank you! This actually works. I don't know exactly how, but I'm going to find out :D